# Rails: TypeError: NullDecompressor is not a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try execute `bundle exec puma -e production -b tcp://127.0.0.1:3000` or `bundle exec rspec spec/` i get message:

> /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/zip-2.0.2/lib/zip/zip.rb:274:in : NullDecompressor is not a class (TypeError)

I have Rails 4.1.14.1 and Ruby 2.1.4

Comment: run `bundle install`.

Comment: Already, but still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use an older version of the [`rubyzip` gem](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip). In 2013, more precisely in [this commit](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/commit/73d9e1c8a082b14db3aaa6e80dc896223514f6c4), **the `NullDecompressor` has been rewritten from a class to a module**. Now, some of your other code expects it to be a class but finds a module, that's why you get the `TypeError`.

So it seems that using the [`rubyzip-1.0.0` version](https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip/tree/v1.0.0) might fix your issue.

BTW, your error points to `zip-2.0.2` which seems to be [an even older gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/zip/2.0.2/Zip/NullDecompressor) that have been later converted to the `rubyzip-1.0.0` gem.

Comment: Perfect!! I made the migration to zip gem. Thanks!!